# Add periods to demand pandas dataframe that have zero demand for unique combinations of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this.

```
Location   Part    UnitCost   DemandType   Demand    Period
NL         12345   6          GENERAL      4         2017-10-01 00:00:00
NL         12345   6          GENRAL       6         2017-12-01 00:00:00
```

There was no demand in November, but there is no record of that. It is just left then. I want that added. What can I do to make it into this:

```
Location   Part    UnitCost   DemandType   Demand    Period
NL         12345   6          GENERAL      4         2017-10-01 00:00:00
NL         12345   6          GENERAL      0         2017-11-01 00:00:00
NL         12345   6          GENERAL      6         2017-12-01 00:00:00
```

Furthermore, I want to add all months with zero demand from 2017-10-01 till 2020-03-01.
It is important that this is done for the unique combination of Location and Part. There are more than 100 unique combinations of Location and Part in my dataframe.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period']) #Make sure Period is datatime dtype
df1 = df.set_index('Period') #Set Index for resample in next statement
df1.resample('MS').ffill().assign(Demand=df1['Demand']).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Period Location   Part  UnitCost DemandType  Demand
0 2017-10-01       NL  12345         6    GENERAL     4.0
1 2017-11-01       NL  12345         6    GENERAL     0.0
2 2017-12-01       NL  12345         6     GENRAL     6.0
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit.
There are also other Location-Part combinations like: US 54321 and CN 23451